# SWT editable Combo - select index when text box is not empty

Tags: java, combobox, swt

Using SWT editable `Combo`, I'm trying to make my program select a specific index.

I see the following behaviour: if the index before I go and try to change it is other than -1 - the select works just fine. But if the index is -1, my trying to select doesn't work. The combo text box gets the new value but whenn trying to get currentSelectionIndex I get -1 and not 0.

The code I'm using is:

```
if (cmbModel.getSelectionIndex() == -1) {                 
     cmbModel.select(0);
}
```

UPDATE:
After more investigaion I see that if the textbox is empty when i try to set the current index - it works. If user writes something in the combos' text box - the select doesn't work.

Comment: On Windows 7 selecting an item of an editable Combo works just fine. What OS are you running on? Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem?

Comment: Combo.select(int index) won't execute a selection if index is smaller than the number of elements in the combo box (+1, since it's zero-indexed). Check to see if your combo is initializing properly and doesn't have an empty model.